# best way to find files recursively that have the same name but are actually different using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have about 15000 images in nested file structure whose names are SKUS. I need to make sure that there are no files with the same SKU that are actually different files.

For example, if I have two or more files named: `MYSKU.jpg`, I need to make sure that none of them are different from each other.

What's the best way to do that in a bash command?

Comment: I do not really understand how this is being upvoted so much without any evidence of an attempt of the author to tackle the problem

Comment: @Pankrates I was asking for the 'best' or most accepted way, I was hoping for a one liner; that said, I only posed the question because I didn't find any other SO questions that I felt answered it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to solve the task for you completely, but here are some useful ingredients that you can try and integrate:

```
find /path -type f   # gives you a list of all files in /path
```

you can iterate through the list like this

```
for f in $(find /path -type f -name '*.jpg'); do
  ...
done
```

now you can think of things you need to collect within the loop. I'd suggest

```
base=$(basename $f)
full_path=$f
hash=$(echo $f | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

you can now store this information in three columns in a file, so that each line contains all you need to know about a file to find the duplicates.

since you didn't explain how you need to deal with the duplicates, here's just a suggestion how to spot them. then it's up to you what to do with them.

given the list we obtained above, you can store two copies of it: one is just sorted by basename, the other is sorted by basename *excluding duplicates*:

```
sort -k2    list.txt | column -t > list.sorted.txt       
sort -k2 -u list.txt | column -t > list.sorted.uniq.txt
```

here I assume the basename is in the second column

now run

```
diff list.sorted.txt list.sorted.uniq.txt
```

to see the files that have the same name. from each row you can now extract the MD5 checksum to verify if they're really different and also the full path in order to perform some action like `mv`, `rm`, `ln` etc.

Comment: I once [implemented something similar in Perl](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/diffcluster); more efficient programs exist to do such things, such as [freedup](http://freedup.org/).

Comment: You can also filter on file size first, before hashing, if you want to optimize.

Comment: Iterating over a file using `for f in $(find …)` is not a best practice. For one thing, if any found path contains whitespace, it will break. For another thing, it's actually significantly slower than using `find`s own `-exec` or using the shell's own recursive globbing. (Many modern shells support recursive globs, including bash 4.)

Comment: To add to what kojiro said, it's very slow because the command substitution must complete before iterations can be performed.

Comment: +1 for the helpful pointers; however, @kojiro makes good points; if you do stick with `find`, use `while` instead of `for`: `find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | while read -d '' -r f; do` (or use process substitution in lieu of the pipe). Also, if you want to sort by field 2 (only), it must be `sort -k2,2`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to scan directory for all files and check which one have the same name but different content based on the md5 checksum

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory to scan
scan_dir=$1

[ ! -d "$1" ] && echo "Usage $0 <scan dir>" && exit 1

# Associative array to save hash table
declare -A HASH_TABLE
# Associative array of full path of items
declare -A FULL_PATH


for item in $( find $scan_dir -type f ) ; do
    file=$(basename $item)
    md5=$(md5sum $item | cut -f1 -d\ )
    if [ -z "${HASH_TABLE[$file]}" ] ; then
        HASH_TABLE[$file]=$md5
        FULL_PATH[$file]=$item
    else
        if [ "${HASH_TABLE[$file]}" != "$md5" ] ; then
            echo "differ $item from ${FULL_PATH[$file]}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Usage  (assume that you name the script file as `scan_dir.sh` :

```
$ ./scan_dir.sh /path/to/you/directory
```

Comment: +1, but (a) don't use `for` to parse command output (see the comments on @Pavel's answer or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a discussion and alternatives), (b) double-quote all `$scan_dir` and `$item` references, (c) send the usage info to _stderr_, given that you're reporting an _error_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle it with bash 4:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash -vx

#!/usr/local/bin/bash -vx

shopt -s globstar # turn on recursive globbing
shopt -s nullglob # hide globs that don't match anything
shopt -s nocaseglob # match globs regardless of capitalization

images=( **/*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png} ) # all the image files
declare -A homonyms # associative array of like named files

for i in "${!images[@]}"; do # iterate over indices
    base=${images[i]##*/} # file name without path
    homonyms["$base"]+="$i " # Space delimited list of indices for this basename
done

for base in "${!homonyms[@]}"; do # distinct basenames
    unset dupehashes; declare -A dupehashes # temporary var for hashes
    indices=( ${homonyms["$base"]} ) # omit quotes to allow expansion of space-delimited integers
    (( ${#indices[@]} > 1 )) || continue # ignore unique names
    for i in "${indices[@]}"; do
        dupehashes[$(md5 < "${images[i]}")]+="$i "
    done

    (( ${#dupehashes[@]} > 1 )) || continue # ignore if same hash
    echo
    printf 'The following files have different hashes: '
    for h in "${!dupehashes[@]}"; do
        for i in ${dupehashes[$h]}; do # omit quotes to expand space-delimited integer list
            printf '%s %s\n' "$h" "${images[i]}"
        done
    done
done
```

I know the above looks like a lot, but I think with 15k images you really want to avoid `open()`ing and checksumming ones you don't have to, so this approach is tuned to narrow the dataset down to duplicate filenames and only then hash the contents. As others have said earlier, you can make this even faster by checking file sizes before hashing, but I'll leave that part unfinished.